# Is it possible to add more values in a for in loop Liquid Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Here's my code

```
{% for filter_prefix in filter_prefixes %}
{{ filter_prefix }}
{% endfor %}
```

There are some values I want to add to the `filter_prefixes`, example: Type...
Can I do it like this?

```
{% for filter_prefix in filter_prefixes %}
{% filter_prefix = 'Type' %}
{{ filter_prefix }}
{% endfor %}
```

To list all the `filter_prefixes` and added the `Type` value as well.

Please help me with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just output the value you want. There is no need to add it to the loop since it is just something you output anyway.

```
Type
{% for filter_prefix in filter_prefixes %}
   {{ filter_prefix }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or use the Shopify Array filters **split** and **join**. So you join your existing array filter_prefixes into a string, append **Type** and then split that back into an array.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I need it to be in the `filter_prefixes` array? is there anyway to add more value if the `filter_prefixes` already have values in it?

Comment: Well, your example showed zero use cases for that, so whatever. And yes. Just split the existing array into a string, add your new value and do a join. Shopify has documentation.  https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters where you can see all the easy stuff you can do. Split/Join... simple.

Comment: Sorry about that, cause ENglish is not my first language, So i can't really describe it much better. Thank you